# 8 Puzzle Code. Having Issues with my my queue not populating and i can not find the location of my bug

Tags: c++, sliding-tile-puzzle

As the title states i'm having trouble finding the error with the way in which my queue is being populated. It should be holding every visited state node until they have been processed. but the queue is not being populated as it should be. Can anyone help me find the bug? Below is my implementation file for the PuzzleStateNode class and source.cpp

EDIT: After more debugging it would seem that the problem lies with the following chunk of code from the solvePuzzle function. The items are never pushed to my queue, and I don't understand why. Could it be an issue with my unordered_set?

```
void solvePuzzle(string stateArray[3][3]) {
    ofstream oFile("output.txt");
    PuzzleStateNode pState(stateArray);
    queue<PuzzleStateNode> puzzleQueue;
    unordered_set<string> visitedPuzzleStateSet;
    if (pState.parityCheck() == true) {     
        puzzleQueue.push(pState);
        for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++){
            PuzzleStateNode myTempState(puzzleQueue.front());
            //puzzleQueue.pop();
            if (visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(myTempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {  // is our value in the set? if not then do the following
                visitedPuzzleStateSet.emplace(myTempState.getPuzzleID()); // add to the list of visited states.             
                if (myTempState.getEmptyXArrayPos() == 0 || myTempState.getEmptyXArrayPos() == 1) { // if a move to the right is available
                    PuzzleStateNode tempState;
                    tempState = PuzzleStateNode(myTempState);
                    tempState.moveEmptySquareRight(tempState.getEmptyXArrayPos(), tempState.getEmptyYArrayPos());
                    if (tempState.checkForSolve() == true) {
                        tempState.printState(oFile);
                        oFile << "Puzzle Solved in " << tempState.getMoveCounter() << " movements of the emtpy tile which are listed below." << endl;
                        tempState.printMoves(oFile);
                        cout << "Puzzle Solved!" << endl << endl << endl;
                        oFile.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (tempState.checkForSolve() != true && visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(tempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {
                        puzzleQueue.push(tempState);
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "you have visited this already" << endl;
                        system("pause");
                    }
                }
```

END EDIT:

PuzzleStateNode.h

```
#pragma once

#include<queue>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
class PuzzleStateNode
{
public:
    PuzzleStateNode();
    PuzzleStateNode(string tempArray[3][3]);
    PuzzleStateNode(const PuzzleStateNode &other);

    int getEmptyXArrayPos();
    int getEmptyYArrayPos();
    int getMoveCounter();
    string getPuzzleID();
    bool parityCheck();
    bool checkForSolve();

    void setPuzzleID();
    void setEmptyXArrayPos(int x);
    void setEmptyYArrayPos(int y);
    void incrimentMoveCounter();
    void pushToMoveQueue(string move);
    void moveEmptySquareDown(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos);
    void moveEmptySquareUp(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos);
    void moveEmptySquareRight(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos);
    void moveEmptySquareLeft(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos);

    void printState(ofstream &oFile);
    void printMoves(ofstream &oFile);

    ~PuzzleStateNode();

private:
    string puzzleStateArray[3][3];
    int moveCounter;
    queue<string> moveQueue;
    int emptyXArrayPos;
    int emptyYArrayPos;
    string puzzleID;
};
```

PuzzleStateNode.cpp

```
  #include "PuzzleStateNode.h"

    using namespace std;



    PuzzleStateNode::PuzzleStateNode()
    {
    }
    PuzzleStateNode::PuzzleStateNode(string tempArray[3][3])
    {
        puzzleID = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                puzzleStateArray[i][j] = tempArray[i][j];
                puzzleID += tempArray[i][j];
                if (puzzleStateArray[i][j] == "E")          {
                    emptyXArrayPos = j;
                    emptyYArrayPos = i;
                }           
            }
        }
        moveCounter = 0;
        moveQueue.push("The following lists the movement of the Empty or 'E' square until the puzzle is solved: ");

    } 
    PuzzleStateNode::PuzzleStateNode(const PuzzleStateNode &other) {
        { puzzleID = "";
            moveCounter = other.moveCounter;
            moveQueue = other.moveQueue;
            emptyXArrayPos = other.emptyXArrayPos;
            emptyYArrayPos = other.emptyYArrayPos;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    puzzleStateArray[i][j] = other.puzzleStateArray[i][j];
                    puzzleID += other.puzzleStateArray[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    int PuzzleStateNode::getEmptyXArrayPos() {
        return emptyXArrayPos;
    }
    int PuzzleStateNode::getEmptyYArrayPos() {
        return emptyYArrayPos;
    }
    int PuzzleStateNode::getMoveCounter() {
        return moveCounter;
    }
    string PuzzleStateNode::getPuzzleID() {
        return puzzleID;
    }
    bool PuzzleStateNode::checkForSolve() {
        if (puzzleStateArray[0][0] == "1" && puzzleStateArray[0][1] == "2" && puzzleStateArray[0][2] == "3" && puzzleStateArray[1][0] == "4" && puzzleStateArray[1][1] == "5" && puzzleStateArray[1][2] == "6" && puzzleStateArray[2][0] == "7" && puzzleStateArray[2][1] == "8" && puzzleStateArray[2][2] == "E") {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    void PuzzleStateNode::setPuzzleID() {
        puzzleID = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                puzzleID += puzzleStateArray[i][j];
            }
        }   
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::setEmptyXArrayPos(int x) {
        emptyXArrayPos = x;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::setEmptyYArrayPos(int y) {
        emptyXArrayPos = y;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::incrimentMoveCounter() {
        moveCounter++;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::pushToMoveQueue(string move) {
        moveQueue.push(move);
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::printMoves(ofstream &oFile) {
        string tempString;
        for (int i = 0; i < moveQueue.size(); i++) {
            cout << moveQueue.front() << endl;
            moveQueue.push(moveQueue.front());
            moveQueue.pop();
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::printState(ofstream &oFile) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                cout << puzzleStateArray[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    void PuzzleStateNode::moveEmptySquareDown(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos) {
            puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos] = puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos + 1][xEmptyPos];
            puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos + 1][xEmptyPos] = "E";
            moveQueue.push("Down");
            moveCounter++;
            cout << "Moving Down" << endl;
            emptyYArrayPos = yEmptyPos + 1;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::moveEmptySquareUp(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos) {
        puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos] = puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos - 1][xEmptyPos];
        puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos - 1][xEmptyPos] = "E";
        moveQueue.push("Up");
        moveCounter++;
        cout << "Moving Up" << endl;
        emptyYArrayPos = yEmptyPos - 1;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::moveEmptySquareLeft(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos) {
        puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos] = puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos - 1];
        puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos - 1] = "E";
        moveQueue.push("Left");
        moveCounter++;
        cout << "Moving Left" << endl;
        emptyXArrayPos = xEmptyPos - 1;
    }
    void PuzzleStateNode::moveEmptySquareRight(int xEmptyPos, int yEmptyPos) {
        puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos] = puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos + 1];
        puzzleStateArray[yEmptyPos][xEmptyPos + 1] = "E";
        moveQueue.push("Right");
        moveCounter++;
        cout << "Moving Right" << endl;
        emptyXArrayPos = xEmptyPos + 1;
    }







    bool PuzzleStateNode::parityCheck()  // counts number of swaps for a bubble sort excluding swaps involving the empty space
    {                           

        enter code here

             // Puzzles with odd swaps have odd parity and are unsolvable. 
        string parityCheckString = "";
        char tempChar;  
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    parityCheckString += puzzleStateArray[i][j];
            }
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (parityCheckString[i] > parityCheckString[i + 1]) {
                    if (parityCheckString[i] == 'E') {
                        tempChar = parityCheckString[i];
                        parityCheckString[i] = parityCheckString[i + 1];
                        parityCheckString[i + 1] = tempChar;

                    }
                    else {
                        tempChar = parityCheckString[i];
                        parityCheckString[i] = parityCheckString[i + 1];
                        parityCheckString[i + 1] = tempChar;
                        counter += 1;
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }   
        if (counter % 2 == 0) {
            cout << "Even Parity, solving the 8 puzzle!" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Parity is odd and puzzle is unsolvable. Skipping to next Puzzle." << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }


    PuzzleStateNode::~PuzzleStateNode()
    {
    }
```

source.cpp

```
#include"PuzzleStateNode.h"
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    void solvePuzzle(string stateArray[3][3]);
    ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    ofstream outFile("output.txt");
    string puzNum;
    int numberOfPuzzles;
    string junk;


    getline(inFile, puzNum); // read number of puzzles
    numberOfPuzzles = stoi(puzNum); // convert value to int. 

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPuzzles; i++) {
        string stateArray[3][3];  // populates a temporary puzzle state. 
        string temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                while (temp != "1" && temp != "2" && temp != "3" && temp != "4" && temp != "5" && temp != "6" && temp != "7" && temp != "8" && temp != "E") {
                    temp = inFile.get();
                }
                stateArray[i][j] = temp;
                temp = inFile.get();
            }
        }
        solvePuzzle(stateArray);
    }   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



void solvePuzzle(string stateArray[3][3]) {
    ofstream oFile("output.txt");
    PuzzleStateNode pState(stateArray);
    queue<PuzzleStateNode> puzzleQueue;
    unordered_set<string> visitedPuzzleStateSet;
    if (pState.parityCheck() == true) {     
        puzzleQueue.push(pState);
        for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++){
            PuzzleStateNode myTempState(puzzleQueue.front());
            //puzzleQueue.pop();
            if (visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(myTempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {  // is our value in the set? if not then do the following
                visitedPuzzleStateSet.emplace(myTempState.getPuzzleID()); // add to the list of visited states.             
                if (myTempState.getEmptyXArrayPos() == 0 || myTempState.getEmptyXArrayPos() == 1) { // if a move to the right is available
                    PuzzleStateNode tempState;
                    tempState = PuzzleStateNode(myTempState);
                    tempState.moveEmptySquareRight(tempState.getEmptyXArrayPos(), tempState.getEmptyYArrayPos());
                    if (tempState.checkForSolve() == true) {
                        tempState.printState(oFile);
                        oFile << "Puzzle Solved in " << tempState.getMoveCounter() << " movements of the emtpy tile which are listed below." << endl;
                        tempState.printMoves(oFile);
                        cout << "Puzzle Solved!" << endl << endl << endl;
                        oFile.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (tempState.checkForSolve() != true && visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(tempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {
                        puzzleQueue.push(tempState);
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "you have visited this already" << endl;
                        system("pause");
                    }
                }               
                if (myTempState.getEmptyXArrayPos() == 1 || myTempState.getEmptyXArrayPos() == 2) {
                    PuzzleStateNode tempState;
                    tempState = PuzzleStateNode(myTempState);
                    tempState.moveEmptySquareLeft(tempState.getEmptyXArrayPos(), tempState.getEmptyYArrayPos());
                    tempState.incrimentMoveCounter();                   
                    if (tempState.checkForSolve() == true) {
                        tempState.printState(oFile);
                        oFile << "Puzzle Solved in " << tempState.getMoveCounter() << " movements of the emtpy tile which are listed below." << endl;
                        tempState.printMoves(oFile);
                        cout << "Puzzle Solved!" << endl;
                        oFile.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (tempState.checkForSolve() != true && visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(tempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {
                        puzzleQueue.push(tempState);
                    }               
                    else {
                        cout << "you have visited this state" << endl;
                        system("pause");
                    }
                }
                if (myTempState.getEmptyYArrayPos() == 0 || myTempState.getEmptyYArrayPos() == 1) {
                    PuzzleStateNode tempState;
                    tempState = PuzzleStateNode(myTempState);
                    tempState.moveEmptySquareDown(tempState.getEmptyXArrayPos(), tempState.getEmptyYArrayPos());
                    if (tempState.checkForSolve() == true) {
                        tempState.printState(oFile);
                        oFile << "Puzzle Solved in " << tempState.getMoveCounter() << " movements of the emtpy tile which are listed below." << endl;
                        tempState.printMoves(oFile);
                        cout << "Puzzle Solved!" << endl;
                        oFile.close();
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (tempState.checkForSolve() != true && visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(tempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {
                        puzzleQueue.push(tempState);
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "you have this state already" << endl;
                        system("pause");
                    }

                }
                if (myTempState.getEmptyYArrayPos() == 1 || myTempState.getEmptyYArrayPos() == 2) {
                    PuzzleStateNode tempState(myTempState);
                    tempState = PuzzleStateNode(myTempState);
                    tempState.moveEmptySquareUp(tempState.getEmptyXArrayPos(), tempState.getEmptyYArrayPos());

                    if (tempState.checkForSolve() == true) {
                        tempState.printState(oFile);
                        oFile << "Puzzle Solved in " << tempState.getMoveCounter() << " movements of the emtpy tile which are listed below." << endl;
                        tempState.printMoves(oFile);
                        cout << "Puzzle Solved!" << endl;
                        oFile.close();
                        return;
                    }                   
                    else if (tempState.checkForSolve() != true && visitedPuzzleStateSet.find(tempState.getPuzzleID()) == visitedPuzzleStateSet.end()) {
                        puzzleQueue.push(tempState);
                    }

                    else {
                        cout << "have visited this state already" << endl;
                        system("pause");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        oFile.close();
        return;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Lot of code there, probably too much to qualify as a [mcve], but the point is moot as PuzzleStateNode.h is missing.

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: input file is as follows.
10

7 5 4
3 6 2
E 8 1

2 1 8
4 3 5
E 6 7

4 2 E
5 1 6
7 3 8
1. 8 4
7 5 E
6 2 3
5 2 1
8 6 4
3 E 7
8 4 E
5 7 6
3 1 2
7 E 3
4 1 8
6 2 5
1. 4 3
6 E 8
7 2 5
6 1 7
4 3 5
E 2 8
5 3 2
6 E 4
7 1 8

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I was never resetting puzzle id's after copying so all puzzle states had the same ID for my set.